# Node-Sass can't find python even if it is instaleld

Tags: python, node.js, node-sass

So when I run `npm install node-sass` for an application, i get the following error:
 [image]
Full log found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c3UmGRgbuYwyLA522Qph_ywHVnsWHUef):

I have installed python and the path where it says it cant find python, it is installed. I even added the environment variables:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running this command before installing your module

```js
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```